Why Are New Messages Not Appearing in Chronological Order in My Chat Application?

I'm building a chat application where users can send and receive messages. However, I'm facing an issue where new messages are not displayed in the correct order on the frontend. Here's the scenario:

When I send a message, it appears on the right side (as expected, since I'm the sender).
When I receive a reply, it appears on the left side (also correct, as the other user is the sender).
However, when I send another message, it is added below my previous message instead of being displayed as the latest message in the conversation.

The expected behavior is for all messages to appear in chronological order (oldest to newest).
My Backend Code:
Here’s my service to fetch user chats from the database:
export const getUserChatsService = async (
  currentUserId: number,
  otherUserId: number
) => {
  const chats = await prisma.chat.findMany({
    where: {
      OR: [
        { senderId: currentUserId, receiverId: otherUserId },
        { senderId: otherUserId, receiverId: currentUserId },
      ],
    },
    include: {
      sender: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          fullName: true,
          profileImage: true,
        },
      },
      receiver: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          fullName: true,
          profileImage: true,
        },
      },
      Message: {
        orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' }, // Sorting messages by newest first
      },
    },
  });
  return chats;
};


Frontend Code:
Here’s how I render the chat messages:

{data?.data?.map((chat) => (
  <div key={chat.id} className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
    {chat?.Message?.map((message) => {
      const isSender = message.senderId === user.id;

      return (
        <div
          key={message.id}
          className={`flex ${isSender ? 'justify-end' : 'justify-start'}`}
        >
          <div
            className={`max-w-xs p-3 rounded-lg text-white ${
              isSender ? 'bg-primary' : 'bg-primary/70'
            }`}
          >
            <p>{message.message}</p>
            <span className="text-xs">
              {new Date(message.createdAt).toLocaleTimeString()}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
))}



Problem Analysis:

Messages are fetched in descending order (orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' }).
On the frontend, the messages are rendered directly without reordering them for display purposes.
This seems to cause the latest messages to not appear at the end of the chat conversation as expected.

Question:
How can I ensure that messages are displayed in chronological order (oldest to newest) on the frontend?

Should I change the orderBy clause in the backend to asc?
Or is there a better way to handle this sorting on the frontend?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

So (1) you try to fetch messages in descending chronological order, but (2) you want them in ascending chronological order, but (3) you get them in some third order that matches the structure of your query instead of your attempt to sort it?

if i fetch data is ascending or descending order this issue not gone

I think I see your problem. You have two separate chat-s — one in each direction — and you render all messages in one chat followed by all messages in the other chat. You need to merge the two Message arrays somehow, or else you need to store the whole conversation in a single chat.

please write the proper answer with code

Please feel free to write it yourself, now that you know what the issue is. (Self-answered questions are allowed on Stack Overflow.)
